# How to change date time column in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, date

In My application i am inserting excel sheet data into data base. In this process i am filtering data base records based on giving textbox month and year. If any records occurs based on user giving moth and year textbox those filter records are deleted and again insert in this process i have date column in excel in my excel date format is `DD\MM\YYY`. when i filter records in that row field from data base column in that i have to take `<System.Datetime>("Date")//data base field` here change the type like `MM\DD`. I need to change same as excel date `DD\MM\YYY` format can anyone tell me

My code is:

```
int month1;
bool validMonth = int.TryParse(txtmonth.Text, out month1);
int year1;
bool validYear = int.TryParse(txtyear.Text, out year1);
var filteredRows = from row in DBdt.AsEnumerable()
    let  date = row.Field<System.DateTime>("Date")
    where date.Month == month1 && date.Year == year1
    select row;

DataRow[] dr = filteredRows.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

DataFormat is a property of BoundField control and doesn't affect any other control.

try this,

```
int month1;
bool validMonth = int.TryParse(txtmonth.Text, out month1);
int year1;
bool validYear = int.TryParse(txtyear.Text, out year1);
var filteredRows = from row in DBdt.AsEnumerable()
    let  date = row.Field<System.DateTime>("Date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
    where date.Month == month1 && date.Year == year1
    select row;

DataRow[] dr = filteredRows.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi @Anish Menon, when i am using that format getting error

Comment: please let me know what is the error your getting as per that i can solve that issue.

Comment: HI @Anish Menon, It not accepting the code when i am adding that type`"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"` as like your code it showing read line under that line can you tell me

Comment: try this `date = row.Field<System.DateTime>("Date","dd/MM/yyyy")`